# How to obtain width of longtable?

Tags: tables, longtable, width

I need to create multiple tables of the same width, one of them needs to be a longtable due to spanning multiple pages. I could set the width of all of them to a predefined value. However, I would rather like to take it from the natural width of one of the tables. How could I do this?

Answer (score 6):

Inside the `threeparttablex` package I use this construction to detect the width from within the table itself

```
\noalign{\begingroup
\setlength\TPTL@width{0pt}
\renewcommand\LT@entry[2]{\global\advance\TPTL@width by ##2}
\@nameuse{LT@\roman{LT@tables}}
\endgroup}
```

Then the width is then stored in `\TPTL@width` globally. It takes a few compilations before it is stable.

Answer (score 3):

Write the longtable into an external file and read it in with `\LTXtable`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\usepackage{ltxtable}
\newsavebox\TBox
\begin{document}

\savebox\TBox{%
\begin{tabular}{@{} ccc @{}}\hline
One & Two & Three\\\hline
\end{tabular}}

\begin{center}
\usebox\TBox
\end{center}

\begin{filecontents*}{myLongtab.tex}
\begin{longtable}{@{} ccX @{}}\hline
1 & 2 & 3\\\hline
\end{longtable}
\end{filecontents*}

\LTXtable{\wd\TBox}{myLongtab}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

This is a solution without getting the width of one of the table but you may combine it with daleif’s answer.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabu,longtable}
\newlength{\mytablen}
\setlength{\mytablen}{5cm}
\begin{document}
Short Table:

\begin{tabu} to \mytablen {|XX|}
1 & 2\\
3 & 4\\
\end{tabu}

\bigskip
Long Table:

\begin{longtabu} to \mytablen {|XX|}
1 & 2\\
3 & 4\\
\end{longtabu}
\end{document}
```

Note that the `{longtabu}` is centered by default an that `longtable` needs to be loaded manually

Answer (score 1):

Similar to daleif's solution, hack into `longtable` package:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{longtable}

\makeatletter
\def\getLTwidth#1{%
  \begingroup
  #1=0pt%
  \def\LT@entry##1##2{\advance#1 by ##2}%
  \LT@save@row
  \edef\X{\noexpand#1=\the#1\relax}%
  \expandafter\endgroup\X}
\makeatother
\newlength\LTwidth

\begin{document}

\begin{longtable}[l]{|c|c|}
foo & bar \\
1 & 1234567 \\
\end{longtable}

\getLTwidth\LTwidth
\noindent\rule{\LTwidth}{1pt}

\end{document}
```

`\getLTwidth` gets the last `longtable`'s width and set the variable locally.

Comment: you don't need `threeparttablex` in my solution above

Comment: That's true, I didn't noticed it. The code is still a little different. I use `\LT@save@row` outside `longtable` package, and (maybe unnecessary) set the dimension locally.

Answer (score 0):

This version uses the values stored in the aux file.  It has the advantage of working BEFORE the longtable (albeit on the second pass).

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{longtable}

\newlength{\LTwidth}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\getLTwidth}[1][\empty]% #1 = longtable index (optional)
{\bgroup% for \count1 and \LT@entry
  \ifx\empty#1\relax
    \count1=\value{LT@tables}% default
    \advance\count1 by 1
  \else
    \count1=#1\relax
  \fi
  \@ifundefined{LT@\@roman\count1}{\LTwidth=\textwidth}{%
    \LTwidth=0pt%
    \def\LT@entry##1##2{\advance\LTwidth by ##2}%
    \csname LT@\@roman\count1\endcsname
  }%
  \global\LTwidth=\LTwidth
\egroup}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\getLTwidth% before
\noindent\rule{\LTwidth}{1pt}

\begin{longtable}[l]{|c|c|}
foo & bar \\
1 & 1234567 \\
\end{longtable}

\getLTwidth[\arabic{LT@tables}]% after
\noindent\rule{\LTwidth}{1pt}

\end{document}
```