# threeparttablex table notes for tabu tabulars with less than \textwidth

Tags: tables, notes, tabu

`threeparttablex` can be used to add table notes to `tabu` tabulars*. If the tabular spans \textwidth, the output is as expected. It seems however that the *tablenotes* environment does not adjust its width if the tabular is narrow, although of course this would be desirable.

1) Is there any option/command which is intended to automatically adjust the *tablenotes* environment's width?

2) If not, is there a workaround?

@ 2) According to [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/16253/14697), `threeparttablex` does know the tabular's width. Moreover, given that for the `threeparttable` package, which `threeparttablex` supposedly builds upon, the package documentation states "you can redefine the whole tablenotes environment", it seems that it should be possible to find a workaround.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{tabu}
\usepackage{threeparttablex}

\begin{document}    
\centering
\begin{ThreePartTable}
    \begin{tabu} to .4\textwidth {XX}
        a & b   \\\toprule
        0 & 1   \\\bottomrule
    \end{tabu}
    \begin{tablenotes}
        \footnotesize
        \item[*] This is a long table note text, long enough to exceed the table's width.
    \end{tablenotes}
\end{ThreePartTable}
\end{document}
```

*`threeparttablex` is designed to extend `threeparttable` to `longtable`. Even though the manual does not mention it, `threeparttablex` works with `tabu`, which `threeparttable` does not. Replacing `threeparttablex`'s *ThreePartTable* environment in the above code with a *threeparttable* environment gives an "Extra }, or forgotten \endgroup." error.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I don't know how to do it with `threeparttablex`, but it seems that the old `threeparttable` should be sufficient: the former is for `longtable` and you don't seem to be using `longtabu` (I'm afraid that one should rewrite `threeparttablex` for using the `longtabu` environment).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{tabu}
\usepackage{threeparttable}

\usepackage{xpatch}
\makeatletter
\chardef\TPT@@@asteriskcatcode=\catcode`*
\catcode`*=11
\xpatchcmd{\threeparttable}
  {\TPT@hookin{tabular}}
  {\TPT@hookin{tabular}\TPT@hookin{tabu}}
  {}{}
\catcode`*=\TPT@@@asteriskcatcode
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\centering
\begin{threeparttable}
    \begin{tabu} to .4\textwidth {XX}
        a & b   \\\toprule
        0 & 1   \\\bottomrule
    \end{tabu}
    \begin{tablenotes}
        \footnotesize
        \item[*] This is a long table note text, long enough to exceed the table's width.
    \end{tablenotes}
\end{threeparttable}

\end{document}
```

[image]

---

If you don't have `xpatch`, then change the line

```
\xpatchcmd{\threeparttable}
```

into

```
\expandafter\patchcmd\csname\string\threeparttable\endcsname
```

and load `etoolbox` instead of `xpatch`.

---

How does the patch work? There is, in `threeparttable.sty` a macro called `\TPT@hookin` which wants as argument the name of the table making environment. The `threeparttable` environment executes `\TPT@hookin{tabular}`, `\TPT@hookin{tabular*}` and `\TPT@hookin{tabularx}`, so we simply want to add `\TPT@hookin{tabu}`.

There's a small complication in the fact that Donald Arsenau changes the category code of `*` to 11 when defining `\threeparttable`. The patching macros provided by `etoolbox`, `xpatch` or even `regexpatch` all disassemble the command to patch and rebuild it in order to see if there's something with category codes that would make the patched macro behave differently from what's expected, so we need to take care of that change: the `*` is set to category code 11 and than its original category code is restored.

Comment: Thanks, problem solved. I've added the reason for having used `threeparttablex` to the question. Your patch does interfere with other `threeparttablex` tables (now: narrow table notes for wide tables), however, since besides the note issue the patch does make `threeparttable` work with `tabu`, I replaced `threeparttablex`. I'd be interested in what exactly the patch does, could you give a hint on that?

Comment: Great answer! Perhaps it should be mentioned that loading the `caption` package before the patch results in compilation errors. Loading it afterwards though, seems to be ok though.

Comment: I'd like to also add that the same applies for the `subfig` package. Load it after the patch, not before.