# what's wrong with my ctable?

Tags: tables, ctable

I can't seem to pinpoint the problem with the table below and would appreciate some help. Something simple I am sure, but I can't see it...

```
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage{ctable}

\begin{document}

\ctable[
caption = Summary of model characteristics.,
label = tab:modelSummary,
doinside=\scriptsize,
pos=h
]{lllllll}{
\tnote{For UK grid.}
\tnote[b]{ENTEC emissions are used for shipping.}
\tnote[c]{Based on analysis of extracted `baseline' air-masses.}
}{                  \FL
model    & type       & boundary           & meteorology & chemistry    & grid\tmark   & emissions\tmark[b] \NN
     &            & conditions         &             & (km)         &              &  \ML
aea     & Eulerian   & STOCHEM            & WRF3        & CB05         & 12           & NAEI/EMEP \NN
aqum    & Eulerian   & GEMS/MACC          & UM          & UKCA/RAQ     & ?            & NAEI/EMEP \NN
     &            &                    &             &              &              & ENTEC \NN
emep    & Eulerian   & EMEP-unified       & WRF3.1.1    & EMEP-unified & 5            & NAEI/EMEP \NN
hert    & Eulerian   & GEMS               & WRF3.2.1    & CB05         & 18           & TNO \NN
kcl     & Eulerian   & STOCHEM            & WRF3.1      & CB05         & 9            & NAEI/EMEP \NN
name    & Eulerian   & Mace Head\tnote[c] & UM          & STOCHEM      & $\approx$10? & NAEI/EMEP \NN
     &            &                    &             &              &              & ENTEC \NN
osrm    & Lagrangian & ?                  & NAME (UM)   & STOCHEM      & 10           & NAEI/EMEP \NN
     &            &                    &             &              &              & ENTEC \NN
ptm     & Lagrangian & Mace Head?         & UM          & MCM3.1       & $\approx$10? & NAEI/EMEP \NN
     &            &                    &             &              &              & GEIA \NN
wrfchem & Eulerian   & ?                  & ?           & ?         & ?          & ? \LL
}


\end{document}
```

Gives:

```
Misplaced alignment tab character &.
\\tnote ...uperscript {\normalfont \textit {#1}}}&
                                                  #2\NN \fi 
l.31 }
```

Comment: The problem is with the `\tnote[c]` command on the Eulerian Mace Head line.  Deleting that command allows compilation.

Comment: The page http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/56683/swallowed-space-after-tnote indicates that `\tnote` is defined in a package called `threeparttable`, which you are not using. Including it allows the table to compile, but it changes the table appearance somewhat.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is the line

```
name    & Eulerian   & Mace Head\tnote[c] & UM          & STOCHEM      & $\approx$10? & NAEI/EMEP \NN
```

you need to change `\tnote` to `\tmark`:

```
name    & Eulerian   & Mace Head\tmark[c] & UM          & STOCHEM      & $\approx$10? & NAEI/EMEP \NN
```

Your complete code:

```
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage{ctable}

\begin{document}

\ctable[
caption = Summary of model characteristics.,
label = tab:modelSummary,
doinside=\scriptsize,
pos=h
]{lllllll}{
\tnote{For UK grid.}
\tnote[b]{ENTEC emissions are used for shipping.}
\tnote[c]{Based on analysis of extracted `baseline' air-masses.}
}{                  \FL
model    & type       & boundary           & meteorology & chemistry    & grid\tmark   & emissions\tmark[b] \NN
     &            & conditions         &             & (km)         &              &  \ML
aea     & Eulerian   & STOCHEM            & WRF3        & CB05         & 12           & NAEI/EMEP \NN
aqum    & Eulerian   & GEMS/MACC          & UM          & UKCA/RAQ     & ?            & NAEI/EMEP \NN
     &            &                    &             &              &              & ENTEC \NN
emep    & Eulerian   & EMEP-unified       & WRF3.1.1    & EMEP-unified & 5            & NAEI/EMEP \NN
hert    & Eulerian   & GEMS               & WRF3.2.1    & CB05         & 18           & TNO \NN
kcl     & Eulerian   & STOCHEM            & WRF3.1      & CB05         & 9            & NAEI/EMEP \NN
name    & Eulerian   & Mace Head\tmark[c] & UM          & STOCHEM      & $\approx$10? & NAEI/EMEP \NN
     &            &                    &             &              &              & ENTEC \NN
osrm    & Lagrangian & ?                  & NAME (UM)   & STOCHEM      & 10           & NAEI/EMEP \NN
     &            &                    &             &              &              & ENTEC \NN
ptm     & Lagrangian & Mace Head?         & UM          & MCM3.1       & $\approx$10? & NAEI/EMEP \NN
     &            &                    &             &              &              & GEIA \NN
wrfchem & Eulerian   & ?                  & ?           & ?         & ?          & ? \LL
}


\end{document}
```

[image]