# Why is the tnote of my threeparttable's table cheekily protruding? How can the width be (automatically) adjusted here?

Tags: tables, siunitx, width, threeparttable, tabulary

Why is the tnote of my threeparttable's table cheekily protruding? How can the width be (automatically) adjusted here?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{tabulary}
\usepackage{threeparttable}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.2}
\sisetup{round-mode=places,round-precision=1, add-decimal-zero=true, add-integer-zero=true, round-integer-to-decimal}

\begin{document}



\lipsum[1]



\begin{table}
\centering
\begin{threeparttable}
\caption{Some long boring caption don't fall asleep 2013}

\begin{tabulary}{\textwidth}{@{}*{1}{l}*{2}{S[table-format=3.2]}@{}}
\toprule
& {incl.\ Ingredients A\tnote{1a}} & {excl.\ Ingredients A\tnote{1b}} \\
\midrule
DDDDDDDDDDD & 36.1 & 22.0\\
GGGGGGGGGGGG & 30.9 & 20.0\\
GGGG\tnote{2} & 33.0 & 22.8\\
OOOO\tnote{2} & 33.766 & 24.643
\\ \bottomrule
\end{tabulary}

\begin{tablenotes}
\item [2] Unweighted Average
\item [] Source: radiowaves from outer space 1999
\end{tablenotes}

\end{threeparttable}
\end{table}



\lipsum[2]



\end{document}
```

Comment: You don't have "extendable" columns: use `J` instead of `*{1}{l}` (or `L` if you want ragged right text in case it has to be split across lines).

Comment: @egreg `\begin{tabulary}{\textwidth}{@{}L*{2}{S[table-format=3.2]}@{}} \toprule` (or J instead of L) doesn't seem to do the trick, yet. Is there a difference between `*{1}{L}` and simply `L` ?

Comment: `*{1}{L}` is just a complicated way to say `L`. The argument of `\tnote` is typeset without taking up space, which is usually what's wanted when the note is in the body of the table (but not in the "description" parts such as headers, it seems).

Comment: @egreg hmm, so the "extendable" column don't take the `\tnote`s into account... what to do about it?

Comment: @egreg Are you sure about the body_vs_header bit? Cuz somewhere on SX I read that for "tnotes" in the middle of the body should be typeset as `\newcommand{\mtnote}[1]{\textsuperscript{\TPTtagStyle{#1}}}` an `\mnote` (that is, these should be used if the note is *not* at the end of the line and the line has more text coming after the note).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`\tnote` typesets its argument in a zero width box, so it won't influence the typesetting of the data. This *might* be not wanted in headers or descriptions; you can add a command that mimicks the work of `\tnote` but uses the full width.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{tabulary}
\usepackage{threeparttable}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.2}
\sisetup{round-mode=places,
 round-precision=1,
 add-decimal-zero=true,
 add-integer-zero=true,
 round-integer-to-decimal}

% This is like `\tnote`, but uses the space of the argument    
\newcommand\stnote[1]{\textsuperscript{\TPTtagStyle{#1}}}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1]

\begin{table}[ht]
\centering
\begin{threeparttable}
\caption{Some long boring caption don't fall asleep 2013}

\begin{tabulary}{\textwidth}{@{} L *{2}{S[table-format=3.2]}@{}}
\toprule
& {incl.\ Ingredients A\stnote{1a}} & {excl.\ Ingredients A\stnote{1b}} \\
\midrule
DDDDDDDDDDD   & 36.1   & 22.0   \\
GGGGGGGGGGGG  & 30.9   & 20.0   \\
GGGG\tnote{2} & 33.0   & 22.8   \\
OOOO\tnote{2} & 33.766 & 24.643 \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabulary}

\begin{tablenotes}
\item [2] Unweighted Average
\item [] Source: radiowaves from outer space 1999
\end{tablenotes}

\end{threeparttable}
\end{table}

\lipsum[2]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Note that in order to do something sensible with `tabulary` you have to add at least an "undetermined width column", specified with one character from `LCRJ` each one denoting the desired alignment in the column cells: left alignment (ragged right), centering, right alignment (ragged left), justified.

---

A slightly different definition that allows using `\stnote` in the caption without it appearing in the list of tables: change the definition of `\stnote` with

```
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\makeatletter
\apptocmd{\TPT@begintabbox}{\let\mTPTprint\@firstofone}{}{}
\apptocmd{\threeparttable}{\let\mTPTprint\relax}{}{}
\newcommand\stnote[1]{\protect\mTPTprint{\textsuperscript{\TPTtagStyle{#1}}}}
\newcommand\mTPTprint[1]{}
\makeatother
```

Comment: about tabulary and LCRJ: I was using `L` by default (only in the MWE above did the `l` somehow slip in ;)

Comment: ok... so it's just like the `\mnote` (see my comment @ my question above) which I'd already been using for "middle-notes"... see your answer to this question: http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/56686/27721

Comment: I just found out the the `\mtnote` will appear in the list of tables, unlike the "original" `\tnote` (cf `threeparttable` manual). How could I make sure that also the `\mtnote` does *not* appear in the LoT ?

Comment: ps: `\mtnote` (or `\stnote`) will (unlike `\tnote`) appear in the LoT *only if* it's being used in the **`\caption`** of the `threeparttable`...

Comment: @nuttyaboutnatty I don't understand what you mean. Can you add an example?

Comment: `\begin{threeparttable}
\caption{This is my long\mtnote{1} and complicated caption\tnote{1}}` -- In `\listoftables` the `1` is dropped only for the original `\tnote`, *not* for your tweaked note.

Comment: I'm using the `microtype`-pkg and this line in my preamble: `\g@addto@macro\@verbatim{\microtypesetup{activate=false}}`, "somewhere" *after* your code. Unfortunately, this returns an `Undefined control sequence. l.84 \g \g@addto@macro\@verbatim{\microtypesetup{activate=false}}` (prior to adding your new code there was no error (with `microtype` or otherwise). To me this is all (mostly) ancient Greek and I trust you blindfoldedly :) What can I do about it?

Comment: @nuttyaboutnatty You probably have a `\makeatletter` before the added code. You're supposed to know what you're doing if using it. :)

Comment: hmm, can't find a another instance of `\makeatletter`. Most `\usepackage`s I put into my *.cls file (cuz otherwise it didn't seem to work); I also put your code there; [here I see a mention that that might be a bad idea](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/62583/is-it-really-bad-to-use-makeatletter-and-makeatother-in-a-package-or-class-fil). Between which sections of code would your code be most happy?

Comment: @nuttyaboutnatty If you put that code in a class file, then `\makeatletter` and `\makeatother` mustn't be used.