# Linenumbers with lineno (edtable) breaks inside threeparttable because of caption

Tags: captions, line-numbering, threeparttable

I'm trying to show linenumbers for tables using `lineno`, i.e. `edtable`. The table is set using `threeparttable` and linenumbers work fine, but compilation fails when including a caption. The error message shown is `you can't use \hrule here except with leaders`. I use the `caption` package, but compilation also fails when using KOMA captions. The MWE illustrates the issue.

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}

\usepackage{threeparttable}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage[edtable]{lineno}

% That's the definition of caption@hrule from caption3.sty
% Redefine something here?
% \makeatletter
% \renewcommand*\caption@hrule{\hrule\@height\z@}
% \makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{table}\centering
\begin{threeparttable}
\caption{A simple table}
\resetlinenumber[1]
\begin{edtable}{tabular}{l*{3}{c}}
                          & \multicolumn{1}{c}{(1)}   & \multicolumn{1}{c}{(2)}   & \multicolumn{1}{c}{(3)}   \\
Variable 1                &  1.85                     & 0.92                      & 1.11                      \\
                          & (0.34)                    & (0.24)                    & (0.14)                    \\
\end{edtable}
\end{threeparttable}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Never an easy question? `;-)`

Comment: @egreg Sorry `;-)`. Brilliant answer, as usual.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After some headaches:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}

\usepackage[edtable]{lineno}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{threeparttable}

\usepackage{xpatch}
\makeatletter
\newenvironment{etabular}
  {\resetlinenumber[1]\let\@centercr\relax\edtable{tabular}}
  {\endedtable}
\newenvironment{etabular*}
  {\resetlinenumber[1]\let\@centercr\relax\edtable{tabular*}}
  {\endedtable}

\catcode`\*=11
\xpatchcmd{\threeparttable}
 {\TPT@hookarg{tabularx}}
 {\TPT@hookarg{tabularx}\TPT@hookin{etabular}\TPT@hookarg{etabular*}}
 {}{}
\catcode`\*=12
\makeatother


\begin{document}

\begin{table}\centering
\begin{threeparttable}[b]
\caption{A simple table}
\begin{etabular}{l*{3}{c}}
           & \multicolumn{1}{c}{(1)} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{(2)} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{(3)} \\
Variable 1 &  1.85\tnote{1}          & 0.92                    & 1.11                    \\
           & (0.34)                  & (0.24)                  & (0.14)                  \\
\end{etabular}
\begin{tablenotes}
\item[1] A note
\end{tablenotes}
\end{threeparttable}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

1. The `edtable` environment should be made known to `threeparttable`;
2. however we can't pass it to the hooks, because `edtable` has an optional argument, so I use a "wrapper" for it;
3. the command `\resetlinenumber` is not allowed in `threeparttable`, so I hide it in the new environment;
4. a `\@centercr` emitted by `edtable` causes the infamous "Perhaps a missing `\item`" error, so I neutralize it;
5. the `\threeparttable` environment is patched to made the `etabular` environment known to it (see [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/56524/4427)).

Similar patches are made for the `etabular*` environment that internally calls `\begin{edtable}{tabular*}`. One has to use `\TPT@hookarg` instead of `\TPT@hookin`, in this case, like for `tabular*`.

[image]

Comment: If anyone else wants to use this: As noted in the `edtable` style file, `lineno` does not support "sub"-linenumbers. This means that if you reset the linenumber for tables as in the answer above, the linenumber of the document will be reset as well from where the table is included. I solved this by creating a second set of `lineno.sty` and `edtable.sty` where all the relevant macros have new names. It works, but is not a very pretty solution.