# Use of tabu/tabularx and threeparttable with apa6

Tags: tabularx, tabu, apa6, threeparttable

I am trying to use an earlier solution posted [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/56524/5146) which combines the `tabu` and `threeparttable` to stretch table columns according to `\textwidth`. However, as soon as I change the article class to `apa6` the earlier solution produces errors.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,floatsintext,man,donotrepeattitle]{apa6}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{threeparttable,tabu}

\usepackage{xpatch}
\makeatletter
\chardef\TPT@@@asteriskcatcode=\catcode`*
\catcode`*=11
\xpatchcmd{\threeparttable}
{\TPT@hookin{tabular}}
{\TPT@hookin{tabular}\TPT@hookin{tabu}}
{}{}
\catcode`*=\TPT@@@asteriskcatcode
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\centering
\begin{threeparttable}
    \begin{tabu} to .4\textwidth {XX}
        a & b   \\\toprule
        0 & 1   \\\bottomrule
    \end{tabu}
    \begin{tablenotes}
        \footnotesize
        \item[*] This is a long table note text, long enough to exceed the table's width.
    \end{tablenotes}
\end{threeparttable}

\end{document}
```

The errors are:

```
Extra }, or forgotten \endgroup. \end{tabu}
Undefined control sequence. \end{document}
```

My question: How to stretch a tables with `apa6` when also including tablenotes? That is, I am not bound to the `tabu` or `threeparttable` class, but it seems easiest to me.

---

As `tabularx` was suggested as an alternative, it also produces a compilation error when used together with `threeparttable` and `apa6` (but again not when using only the `article` class).

```
\documentclass[a4paper,floatsintext,man,donotrepeattitle]{apa6}
%\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{tabularx,threeparttable}

\begin{document}

\begin{threeparttable}
    \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth} {XX}
        \toprule
        a & b   \\\midrule
        0 & 1   \\\bottomrule
    \end{tabularx}
    \begin{tablenotes}
        \footnotesize
        \item[*] This is a long table note text, long enough to exceed the table's width.
    \end{tablenotes}
\end{threeparttable}

\end{document}
```

produces:

```
Undefined control sequence. \end{document}
Underfull \hbox (badness 10000) in alignment
```

Comment: Do you have any particular reason for using `tabu` instead of `tabularx`? By the way, there's no reason for either, if you just want two columns whose widths sum up to `.4\textwidth`.

Comment: No. Just from reading other answers here `tabu` seemed to be the correct choice. I have no preference whatsoever (other than using the `apa6`class).

Comment: In my opinion, `tabu` is almost never the correct choice; I might be biased.

Comment: @egreg I have found no way to proportionally expand a table with several columns to `\textwidth` (or some proportion of it) without additional packages. I am happy to be proven otherwise. And also happy for solutions involving `tabularx`.

Comment: `\begin{tabular}{p{\dimexpr.2\textwidth-2\tabcolsep}p{\dimexpr.2\textwidth-2\tabcolsep}}` would do.

Comment: @egreg The problem with such an approach is that the example is obviously just a toy example. In my real examples the columns have different widths (which I do not know) and need to scale them proportionally to the actual width. Hence, I would appreciate an example in which I do not need to specify the actual widths, but let a package do that.

Comment: if you will add to preamble `\shorttitle{Some title}`, your second example will work as expected.

Comment: @Zarko Damn, that was an easy fix and a stupid mistake. If you post this as a complete answer the bounty is yours.

Comment: @Henrik, done :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `˙apa6` require to use `\shorttitle{Some title}` in preamble. If you not need it, than it is suffice to add `\shorttitle{}`:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,floatsintext,man,donotrepeattitle]{apa6}
\usepackage{booktabs,tabularx,threeparttable}
\shorttitle{}% short title, can be empty but not deleted

\usepackage{lipsum}% only for test purpose

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]

\begin{center}
\begin{threeparttable}
    \begin{tabularx}{.4\textwidth}{XX}
                    \toprule
        a & b   \\  \midrule
        0 & 1   \\  \bottomrule
    \end{tabularx}
    \begin{tablenotes}
        \footnotesize
        \item[*] This is a long table note text, long enough to exceed the table's width.
    \end{tablenotes}
\end{center}
\end{threeparttable}

\end{document}
```

[image]