# Table fixed width

Tags: tables, longtable, width

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to obtain width of longtable?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/16251/how-to-obtain-width-of-longtable)

I have many tables that I create with `longtable` or `ltablex`.

How can I make all tables the same width?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) Usually, we don't put a greeting or a "thank you" in our posts. While this might seem strange at first, it is not a sign of lack of politeness, but rather part of our trying to keep everything very concise. Upvoting is the preferred way here to say "thank you" to users who helped you.

Comment: This question is very similar to http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/16251/how-to-obtain-width-of-longtable. Please take a look at it as the information there might help you. If so, that's great, and we'll probably close this question as a duplicate just to keep the place tidy and to help people find answers quickly. If not, please edit your question here to explain why so that people can better focus their attention to help you.