# how to use bicaption in longtable without errors

Tags: longtable, bicaption

I'm trying to use bicaption for longtable, but I get this error:

```
Misplaced \noalign. ...tion{example}{A simple longtable example}
```

Here is an example:

```
\documentclass[UTF-8]{ctexart}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{bicaption}
\captionsetup[table][bi-second]{name=Table.}

\begin{document}
\begin{longtable}{|c|c|c|c|}
    \bicaption{example}{A simple longtable example}\label{tab:longtable}\\
    \hline
    \textbf{First entry} & \textbf{Second entry} & \textbf{Third entry} & \textbf{Fourth entry} \\
    \hline
    \endfirsthead
    \multicolumn{4}{c}%
    {\tablename\ \thetable\ -- \textit{Continued from previous page}} \\
    \hline
    \textbf{First entry} & \textbf{Second entry} & \textbf{Third entry} & \textbf{Fourth entry} \\
    \hline
    \endhead
    \hline \multicolumn{4}{r}{\textit{Continued on next page}} \\
    \endfoot
    \hline
    \endlastfoot
    1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\ 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\ 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\ 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\
    1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\ 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\ 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\ 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\
    1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\ 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\ 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\ 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\
    1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\ 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\ 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\ 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\
    1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\ 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\ 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\ 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\
    1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\ 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\ 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\ 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\
    1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\ 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\ 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\ 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\
    1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\ 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\ 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\ 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\
    1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\ 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\ 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\ 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\
    1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\ 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\ 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\ 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\
    1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\ 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\ 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\ 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\
    1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\ 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\ 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\ 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\
\end{longtable}
\end{document}
```

How can I do something to use bicaption in longtable without any errors? Thanks for your replying!

Answer (score 1):

This places `\bicaption` into a savebox and uses the savebox inside longtable using `\multicolumn`.

See also [how to find longtable width](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/16251/how-to-obtain-width-of-longtable?r=SearchResults&s=4%7C56.3552)

```
\documentclass[UTF-8]{ctexart}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{bicaption}
\captionsetup[table][bi-second]{name=Table.}
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\setcaptype}[1]{\def\@captype{#1}\ignorespaces}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\setbox0=\vbox{\hsize=0.5\textwidth% must be less wide than the longtable, but wider than the caption.
  \setcaptype{table}%
  \bicaption{example}{A simple longtable example}\label{tab:longtable}
  \addtocounter{table}{-1}}%
\begin{longtable}{|c|c|c|c|}
    \multicolumn{4}{c}{\usebox0}\\
    \hline
    \textbf{First entry} & \textbf{Second entry} & \textbf{Third entry} & \textbf{Fourth entry} \\
    \hline
    \endfirsthead
    \multicolumn{4}{c}%
    {\tablename\ \thetable\ -- \textit{Continued from previous page}} \\
    \hline
    \textbf{First entry} & \textbf{Second entry} & \textbf{Third entry} & \textbf{Fourth entry} \\
    \hline
    \endhead
    \hline \multicolumn{4}{r}{\textit{Continued on next page}} \\
    \endfoot
    \hline
    \endlastfoot
    1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\ 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\ 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\ 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\
    1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\ 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\ 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\ 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\
    1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\ 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\ 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\ 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\
    1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\ 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\ 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\ 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\
    1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\ 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\ 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\ 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\
    1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\ 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\ 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\ 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\
    1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\ 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\ 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\ 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\
    1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\ 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\ 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\ 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\
    1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\ 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\ 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\ 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\
    1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\ 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\ 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\ 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\
    1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\ 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\ 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\ 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\
    1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\ 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\ 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\ 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\
\end{longtable}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

This was a bug in the `caption` package which seems to be fixed: https://gitlab.com/axelsommerfeldt/caption/-/issues/138

Comment: Thank you fo0r information!