How to make the width of a tcolorbox exactly the same as the longtable inside it?
I have a tcolorbox and inside it, there is a longtable. The problem is that the width of the tcolorbox doesn't match/fit the longtable. Here is a test case to reproduce easily my problem:
\documentclass[11pt]{book}
\usepackage[default]{opensans}
\usepackage{alltt}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{colortbl}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage[total={15.24cm,22.86cm}]{geometry}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{inconsolata}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{mathabx}
\usepackage{microtype}
%
% For creating new commands with an arbitrary number of arguments
\usepackage{newfile}
%
%
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{pifont}
\usepackage{smartdiagram}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage[listings,skins,most]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage[table,xcdraw]{xcolor}
%
%
%
%
% Define a header style command
\newcommand{\longTabHeaderstyle}[1]{\textcolor{white}{#1}}
%
%
%
%
% Space before the table
\setlength{\LTpre}{0pt}
%
% Space after the table
\setlength{\LTpost}{0pt}
%
% Space from the left before the table
\setlength{\LTleft}{0pt}
%
% Space from the right after the table
\setlength{\LTright}{0pt}
%
%
% Define the printDbBreakableTable environment
\newenvironment{printDbBreakableTable}[4]{%
  % Start the tcolorbox
  \begin{tcolorbox}[%
    % Make the box content breakable across pages
    breakable,%
    %
    % Set background color of the box
    colback=white,%
    %
    % Set frame color of the box
    colframe=black,%
    %
    % Set space below the title
    bottomtitle=1mm,%
    %
    % Set space above the title
    toptitle=1mm,%
    %
    % Set thickness of left border
    leftrule=0.15mm,%
    %
    % Set thickness of right border
    rightrule=0.15mm,%
    %
    % Set thickness of bottom border
    bottomrule=0.15mm,%
    %
    % Center the title
    title=\centering #1,%
    %
    % Remove internal padding
    boxsep=0pt,%
    %
    % Remove top padding
    top=0pt,%
    %
    % Remove bottom padding
    bottom=0pt,%
    %
    % Remove left padding
    left=0pt,%
    %
    % Remove right padding
    right=0pt%
  ]%
  %
  % Begin table structure by indicating the number of columns
  \begin{longtable}%
    {#2}%
    %
    % Set header row color
    \rowcolor{black}%
    %
    % The content of the header row
    #3%
    \endhead
    \hline
    %
    % Insert the table's main content
    #4%
  \end{longtable}%
  % End the tcolorbox
  \end{tcolorbox}%
}


\begin{document}

\arrayrulecolor{black}
\begin{printDbBreakableTable}
  {Test a long table}
  {c|c|c|c}
  {%
    \longTabHeaderstyle{H1} & \longTabHeaderstyle{H2} &
    \longTabHeaderstyle{H3} & \longTabHeaderstyle{H4} \\\hline }
  {%
CellValue-1-1 & CellValue-2-1 & CellValue-3-1 & CellValue-4-1 \\\hline
CellValue-1-2 & CellValue-2-2 & CellValue-3-2 & CellValue-4-2 \\\hline
CellValue-1-3 & CellValue-2-3 & CellValue-3-3 & CellValue-4-3 \\\hline
CellValue-1-4 & CellValue-2-4 & CellValue-3-4 & CellValue-4-4 \\\hline
CellValue-1-5 & CellValue-2-5 & CellValue-3-5 & CellValue-4-5 \\\hline
CellValue-1-6 & CellValue-2-6 & CellValue-3-6 & CellValue-4-6 \\\hline
CellValue-1-7 & CellValue-2-7 & CellValue-3-7 & CellValue-4-7 \\\hline
CellValue-1-8 & CellValue-2-8 & CellValue-3-8 & CellValue-4-8 \\\hline
CellValue-1-9 & CellValue-2-9 & CellValue-3-9 & CellValue-4-9 \\\hline
CellValue-1-10 & CellValue-2-10 & CellValue-3-10 & CellValue-4-10 \\\hline
CellValue-1-11 & CellValue-2-11 & CellValue-3-11 & CellValue-4-11 \\\hline
CellValue-1-12 & CellValue-2-12 & CellValue-3-12 & CellValue-4-12 \\\hline
CellValue-1-13 & CellValue-2-13 & CellValue-3-13 & CellValue-4-13 \\\hline
CellValue-1-14 & CellValue-2-14 & CellValue-3-14 & CellValue-4-14 \\\hline
CellValue-1-15 & CellValue-2-15 & CellValue-3-15 & CellValue-4-15 \\\hline
CellValue-1-16 & CellValue-2-16 & CellValue-3-16 & CellValue-4-16 \\\hline
CellValue-1-17 & CellValue-2-17 & CellValue-3-17 & CellValue-4-17 \\\hline
CellValue-1-18 & CellValue-2-18 & CellValue-3-18 & CellValue-4-18 \\\hline
CellValue-1-19 & CellValue-2-19 & CellValue-3-19 & CellValue-4-19 \\\hline
CellValue-1-20 & CellValue-2-20 & CellValue-3-20 & CellValue-4-20 \\
  }
  
\end{printDbBreakableTable}

\end{document}

Is there any way to set the width of the tcolorbox exactly equal to the longtable inside it so that the longtable is mereged to tcolorbox and can have nice rounded corners on all 4 sides?
Thanks in advance

One way is to save the table in a box, measure that width, and set the tcolorbox to be of that width of the box.  See Squeeze tcolorbox to text width.

welcome! please minimise your code by removing unneeded packages and configuration from the example you post here. most of those packages aren't needed for your question.

@PeterGrill hmm ... I don't see that working with longtable's method of determining the column widths over multiple compilations. are you suggesting typesetting it into a single box if it is not too large just to get the width and then discard the box and let longtable do its thing? I'm not sure longtable likes being put in a box ....

yout example doesn't contain page breaks. if your real table does, make the page smaller in your example or include some filler from a package such as lipsum or kantlipsum. otherwise, the easy solution is not to use longtable here at all.

@cfr Actually, the initial example had at least 150 rows inside the longtable, I just put a few rows here. Currently there are two major problems: 1) Although there is \endhead in my longtable, headers don't appear at the beginning of each page 2) tcolorbox is wider than the longtable inside. As I understand we are supposed to ask only one question per thread, I started by the 2nd problem.

To determine the width of a longtable, see https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/16251/how-to-obtain-width-of-longtable

Assuming longtable will run correctly inside tcolorbox.  It takes at least two runs to get the width (aux file).
\documentclass[11pt]{book}
\usepackage[default]{opensans}
\usepackage{alltt}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{colortbl}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage[total={15.24cm,22.86cm}]{geometry}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{inconsolata}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{mathabx}
\usepackage{microtype}
%
% For creating new commands with an arbitrary number of arguments
\usepackage{newfile}
%
%
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{pifont}
\usepackage{smartdiagram}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage[listings,skins,most]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage[table,xcdraw]{xcolor}
%
%
%
%
% Define a header style command
\newcommand{\longTabHeaderstyle}[1]{\textcolor{white}{#1}}
%
%
%
%
% Space before the table
\setlength{\LTpre}{0pt}
%
% Space after the table
\setlength{\LTpost}{0pt}
%
% Space from the left before the table
\setlength{\LTleft}{0pt}
%
% Space from the right after the table
\setlength{\LTright}{0pt}
%
%
% Define the printDbBreakableTable environment
\newenvironment{printDbBreakableTable}[4]{%
  \getLTwidth
  % Start the tcolorbox
  \begin{tcolorbox}[%
    % Make the box content breakable across pages
    breakable,%
    text width={\LTwidth},
    %
    % Set background color of the box
    colback=white,%
    %
    % Set frame color of the box
    colframe=black,%
    %
    % Set space below the title
    bottomtitle=1mm,%
    %
    % Set space above the title
    toptitle=1mm,%
    %
    % Set thickness of left border
    leftrule=0.15mm,%
    %
    % Set thickness of right border
    rightrule=0.15mm,%
    %
    % Set thickness of bottom border
    bottomrule=0.15mm,%
    %
    % Center the title
    title=\centering #1,%
    %
    % Remove internal padding
    boxsep=0pt,%
    %
    % Remove top padding
    top=0pt,%
    %
    % Remove bottom padding
    bottom=0pt,%
    %
    % Remove left padding
    left=0pt,%
    %
    % Remove right padding
    right=0pt%
  ]%
  \par
  %
  % Begin table structure by indicating the number of columns
  \begin{longtable}%
    {#2}%
    %
    % Set header row color
    \rowcolor{black}%
    %
    % The content of the header row
    #3%
    \endhead
    \hline
    %
    % Insert the table's main content
    #4%
  \end{longtable}%
  % End the tcolorbox
  \end{tcolorbox}%
}

\makeatletter
\newlength{\LTwidth}
\newcommand{\getLTwidth}[1][\empty]% #1 = longtable index (optional)
{\bgroup% for \count1 and \LT@entry
  \ifx\empty#1\relax
    \count1=\value{LT@tables}% default
    \advance\count1 by 1
  \else
    \count1=#1\relax
  \fi
  \@ifundefined{LT@\@roman\count1}{\LTwidth=\textwidth}{%
    \LTwidth=0pt%
    \def\LT@entry##1##2{\advance\LTwidth by ##2}%
    \csname LT@\@roman\count1\endcsname
  }%
  \global\LTwidth=\LTwidth
\egroup}
\makeatother


\begin{document}

\arrayrulecolor{black}
\begin{printDbBreakableTable}
  {Test a long table}
  {c|c|c|c}
  {%
    \longTabHeaderstyle{H1} & \longTabHeaderstyle{H2} &
    \longTabHeaderstyle{H3} & \longTabHeaderstyle{H4} \\\hline }
  {%
CellValue-1-1 & CellValue-2-1 & CellValue-3-1 & CellValue-4-1 \\\hline
CellValue-1-2 & CellValue-2-2 & CellValue-3-2 & CellValue-4-2 \\\hline
CellValue-1-3 & CellValue-2-3 & CellValue-3-3 & CellValue-4-3 \\\hline
CellValue-1-4 & CellValue-2-4 & CellValue-3-4 & CellValue-4-4 \\\hline
CellValue-1-5 & CellValue-2-5 & CellValue-3-5 & CellValue-4-5 \\\hline
CellValue-1-6 & CellValue-2-6 & CellValue-3-6 & CellValue-4-6 \\\hline
CellValue-1-7 & CellValue-2-7 & CellValue-3-7 & CellValue-4-7 \\\hline
CellValue-1-8 & CellValue-2-8 & CellValue-3-8 & CellValue-4-8 \\\hline
CellValue-1-9 & CellValue-2-9 & CellValue-3-9 & CellValue-4-9 \\\hline
CellValue-1-10 & CellValue-2-10 & CellValue-3-10 & CellValue-4-10 \\\hline
CellValue-1-11 & CellValue-2-11 & CellValue-3-11 & CellValue-4-11 \\\hline
CellValue-1-12 & CellValue-2-12 & CellValue-3-12 & CellValue-4-12 \\\hline
CellValue-1-13 & CellValue-2-13 & CellValue-3-13 & CellValue-4-13 \\\hline
CellValue-1-14 & CellValue-2-14 & CellValue-3-14 & CellValue-4-14 \\\hline
CellValue-1-15 & CellValue-2-15 & CellValue-3-15 & CellValue-4-15 \\\hline
CellValue-1-16 & CellValue-2-16 & CellValue-3-16 & CellValue-4-16 \\\hline
CellValue-1-17 & CellValue-2-17 & CellValue-3-17 & CellValue-4-17 \\\hline
CellValue-1-18 & CellValue-2-18 & CellValue-3-18 & CellValue-4-18 \\\hline
CellValue-1-19 & CellValue-2-19 & CellValue-3-19 & CellValue-4-19 \\\hline
CellValue-1-20 & CellValue-2-20 & CellValue-3-20 & CellValue-4-20 \\
  }
  
\end{printDbBreakableTable}

\end{document}


This is awesome! It has been at least three weeks that I have been Googling and Googling and Googling to solve this! Not to mention that the documentation of longtable is not very "LaTeX beginner friendly" (at least not for me)! Thank you very much for your time and your help. Is it normal that even though I have \endhead declared with my longtable, the header row is not repeated at the beginning of each page?

I believe longtable regards the entire tcolorbox to be one page.
